# NLP to find canonical strings - seeking guidance on approach

Tags: text-mining, natural-language, word2vec

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/extract-canonical-string-from-a-list-of-noisy-strings) is a post I found that is very similar to my question. However that post is more than 3 years old and I wonder if there's a more established approach to my problem.

Copying a little from the linked post above, suppose I have a corpus with hundreds of thousands of records along the lines:

```
Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope | StarWars.com
Star Wars Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)
Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope - Rotten Tomatoes
Watch Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope Online Free
Star Wars (1977) - Greatest Films
```

I would like to iterate over each entry and suggest the "true" version of it. I could do some basic matching and suggest the most frequent similar phrase.

But is there a more established approach to this? I've heard a lot about word vectors, especially word2vec. Could those tools be used here? Would it make sense to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [entity linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking) or [record linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) fields will be worth checking out as they seem to aim at something similar to your task.

Other than that I think reading about [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) approach might help you. Using this encoding you can distinguish common and uncommon words by their scores. Also you could try clustering tf-idf encoded data and then see similarities of points inside clusters.

Some text summarization algorithms may be also useful for such tasks. See for example [this blog post](https://rare-technologies.com/text-summarization-in-python-extractive-vs-abstractive-techniques-revisited/) on keyword/keyphrase extraction.